# Why https and www are in same URL?

Tags: http, https, dns

Some URLs have both `https` and `www`.
What is the reason behind this?

For example, https://www.facebook.com starts with `https://www`. Is this redundant?

Comment: Why wouldn't they?  `https` and `www` are completely different things in that URL.  When you look up the structure of a URL (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL), what specific part is unclear?  What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

`https` is the protocol. It stands for `hyper text transfer protocol (over TLS)`.

It means that you surf on websites and it is encrypted. By default, the protocol is `http`(no encryption) but this is often redirected to `https`.

`www` is the server.

It can be anything but in most cases, the web server is `www`. Also, the domains redirect you to the webserver (if it is configured that way) if you don't type it in explicitely.

Lastly, `facebook.com` is the domain.

Facebook registered to own the domain `facebook.com`. (`.com` are normally commercial websites) With that, they can deploy servers on addresses that end with `.facebook.com` in a way that they are found.

e.g. https://www.facebook.com means that you want to talk using the protocol `https`(secure web transfer) with the `www` server of `facebook.com`.